# Wordpress XMLRPC(Redstone) permalink not working

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I'm posting on Wordpress using the XMLRPC Api from [Redstone](http://xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/). Although the post is made, the permalink is not set correctly. My code:

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient("xmlrpc link...", true);
HashMap hmContent = new HashMap();
hmContent.put("title", "my post title");
hmContent.put("description", "my new post");
hmContent.put("permaLink", "my-brand-new-post"); <- this should be the permalink
token = client.invoke("metaWeblog.newPost", new Object[] {new Integer(1), 
                                                          "username", 
                                                          "password", 
                                                          hmContent, 
                                                          true} );
```

The permalink I have set is ignored and Wordpress had create a permalink based on the post title.
What could cause this?

**Edit**: adding "wp_slug" value does the trick. Although ["slug"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug) isn't meant for this I think:

```
hmContent.put("wp_slug", "my-brand-new-post");
```

Comment: Can you help me I'm having a problem using the object response after invoking a call to wordpress. After you got the object you name token how did you use the information? I get something like this 

{item_one=info, item_two=info...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try wordpress-java for setting the slug of the post. Have a look at this:

[setWp_slug()](http://wordpress-java.googlecode.com/svn-history/r95/trunk/doc/net/bican/wordpress/Page.html#setWp_slug%28java.lang.String%29) in wordpress-java

Permalink and slug are different things, slug refers to the last "/" divided part of the permalink. You can't change a permalink in full, but you can change the last part via the slug.

Comment: Hi Can, that should also work :) Though the Wordpress-java library is using the Redstone XMLRPC itself right?

Comment: Yes it does, but hides this so that we immortals don't have to deal with untyped arrays and function names as strings :)